# Microsoft Azure Instant vm restoration

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network, azure-hub

Is there a way to restore the vm on a certain recovery point in an instant?
What I meant is the backup process for now will recreate a new VM but what I'm looking for is that the virtual machine will be like rewinded from the way it is three days ago.

I only know the usual process where it will create a new VM and but I don't desire for a new VM to be created but rather turn it back the way it was three days ago.

Comment: Do you backup your VM by using Azure Recovery Service? If you backup your VM, you could do it.

Comment: I tried the Recovery Services Vaults with the Restore Type 'Create Virtual Machine' but what happened is it created a new VM.. It didn't turn back the state of the VM from three days ago

Comment: Please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-arm-restore-vms)

Comment: It's a link to your profile in stackoverflow, is there anything specific to click there?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-arm-restore-vms

Comment: I got to the point that the backup-job is already completed and it created a new VM with the backup of my currently existing VM.. But that did not restore the currently existing VM from what it is three days ago.. And there's nothing on the link that you gave that will rewind my currently existing VM from what it was three days ago..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134342/discussion-between-walter-msft-and-dean-christian-armada).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you backup your VM by using Azure Recovery Service, you could do it. More information please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-arm-restore-vms#restore-a-recovery-point).

However, after you restore your VM, you will get a new Public IP. If you want to change Public IP to original IP, you could delete your original VM or unlink the Public IP from your original VM and assign the public IP to new VM.

[image]

Also, you could use DNS name.

[image]

Comment: you don't need to delete the original vm, you could just unlink the Public IP

Comment: Hi, I tried to do the unlinking of Public IP but what happened is it changed the IP of the the public IP address.. When I try to assign it in the new VM, it labeled as 'unassigned' then IP address changed

Comment: I'm guessing that I should have set the IP address to static first.. Is there a way to revert to my original IP?